# Unix : Avail Space of File mounts

Tags: bash, unix, filesystems

**Problem Statement**

This is regarding the space usage of file system mounted in Unix box

```
df -h -> Gives the total usage/avail/used/used% of all mounts in unix server
```

Is there any other way to find total usage or avail usage % of a filesystem **other than df -h** ?

This is because in my environment there are **few filesystem mounted under '/Data/' as symlinks** ... so df -h is not showing those filesystem. I need to go to "/Data/" and then fire **"ls -lrt | grep ^l"** which is showing my mounts.

I am using du -m  which is giving me disk/FS usage .. but I want to know the avail% or total for that mount.

Is there any way to find out ?

**Purpose**

I want to create utility which will throw alert if space utilization (for only those whose symlinks present inside /Data/) exceeds threshold limit ?

I just need a way to fetch used% of FS.. coding & formatting of the output wont take much time.

**Note:**

- I am not Admin - so no root permissions
- Linux Version : Red Hat 5.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect what you want is the available space on the filesystems which collectively contain a set of directories. This is a bit different than what you asked, since you indicate there are filesystems "mounted...as symlinks" which doesn't sound possible. Symlinks have to point to something which lives on a mounted filesystem, so it should be described by a call to "df -h".

Where do the symlinks under /Data/ point? For instance, if /Data/scratch points to /nfs/fileserverA/scratch1/, then running "df -h /Data/scratch" should report on the underlying filesystem NFS mounted from fileserverA. Or if /Data/images points to /home/myaccount/Pics, then "df -h /Data/images" will report on the /home filesystem.

If you just want the space *used* by several different directories, you can use "du" to tally up the space used by all the files and directories they contain.

Comment: Actually all the filesystem are mounted under one filesystem .... so if i perform df -h /Data/images .. then also it is giving me /Data/ usage ... m not getting Images usage details

Comment: If there's only a single filesystem mounted, there's only one "space available" number to be discovered, the one provided by df. Any of the subdirectories on the filesystem can grow to use up all the space on the filesystem -- they don't have separate limits.